# Infinite sums vs infinite unions

Tags: soft-question, axioms, philosophy

Why is it that

> For every set $S$, there exists a set $\bigcup S$.

is something we take for granted (even though $S$ could be infinite), while

> For every sequence $a_1,a_2,\dots$ of numbers, there exists a number $\sum a_i$.

is not something we take for granted? Addition is viewed as "something to be performed" and we generalize that idea to make meaning of an infinite sum. We don't assume right off the bat that we can perform arbitrary additions. But we don't hold a similar attitude with sets? Isn't unioning
"something that has to be performed" as well?

In both cases, there is a "procedure" that I think is implicit.

Comment: Because sets can be of arbitrary size.  It's only criteria is to "contain stuff" loosely speaking, while numbers only make sense in a finite sense.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the tags. Specifically, I'm not sure about [philosophy] and whether or not [foundations] fits too.

Comment: $\bigcup S$ is the set such that $x\in\bigcup S\Leftrightarrow$ ($x\in s$ for some $s\in S$), while $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ is defined to be the number $L$ such that the sequence of partial sums $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ gets trapped in arbitrarily small neighborhoods of $L$. I wouldn't call $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ a procedure so much as a number satisfying a property, if we're being technical. There is no reason or analogy with set theory making us expect such a property to always be satisfied by some number.

Comment: In any case, you understand that e.g. $1+1+1+\cdots$ doesn't converge, and you understand we can combine the contents of any two bags into a bigger bag, e.g. {evens} and {odds} make {integers}. So there really isn't anything you don't understand here. It has nothing to do with "attitude," it comes from knowing what it is that we're talking about.

Comment: The sums exist.  They just don't always add up to numbers.

Comment: "you understand we can combine the contents of any two bags into a bigger bag" - in general, no, I don't. It makes sense in the finite case. It's not immediately obvious that it makes sense in the nonfinite case. Pretty sure all of this justified axiomatically. That is, we just assume it.

Comment: What exactly do you understand by $\cup S$? This is not standard notation, so you should clarify its meaning before asking for answers.

Comment: @Alex: It is a *very* standard notation. It means the union of all sets which are elements of $S$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Honestly, it is the first time that I encouter it, but admittedly, my knowledge of set theory is restricted to the absolute minimum. Good to learn something new. So, I understand that, from the very beginning, $S$ is a set of sets? I.e. there exist some set $X$ such that $S \subset \mathcal P (X) \simeq 2^X$?

Comment: @Alex: In set theory everything is a set, so every set is a set of sets.

Answer (score 3):

I somewhat disagree with Ittay. This is not a question of size. It's a question of purpose.

**Numbers**, and here I'm referring specifically to real numbers,<sup>1</sup> have a particular purpose. They model the notion of length. When we think about something being long, we think about an interval of time, or distance or otherwise a notion of size, which is a real number. (You could argue that negative numbers make no sense here, but they do from a formal point of view; and we can ignore them for this discussion anyway.)

We know that the infinite sum of finite lengths does not have to be a finite length. It might, under some circumstances, but it does not have to be. We know that, because if we assume that it is, then we can derive all sort of contradictory things like $0=1$.

**Sets**, on the other hand, model the notion of a collection of mathematical objects. When we have two collections, we can talk about their union. But this goes even further. If you already know that $\{X_i\mid i\in I\}$ are all subsets of some $X$, then you can explicitly define the collection which is their union: $$\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i = \{x\in X\mid\exists i\in I: x\in X_i\}$$

The ability to unify a collection of collections into a single collection is useful. And as far as we know, it does not add any contradictions.

---

But here's where things become *very* different between sets and numbers. If we compare sets to numbers, then arbitrary unions are *only* referred to unions indexed by other sets. This is similar to saying that a sum is indexed by another number. So it's a finite sum. So it exists.

On the other hand, "infinite sums" would translate to "union over a proper class of sets", which is rarely ever a set (it is exactly when there are "set many" different sets in our family). So in some sense, summation of sets is stricter and more limiting than summation of numbers.

But the entire thing is about purpose and usability. We have no use for an axiom stating that every series of numbers is again a number; but we have a use for an axiom stating that given a set of sets, we can take its union.

<sub>**Notes:**</sub>

<sub>1. There is no formal definition for the concept of number. True, there is no formal definition for a set either; but as far as context goes, the notion of a set is far more robust than the notion of a number. When I say "two numbers", do I mean natural numbers, integers, rationals, real, complex, ordinal, cardinal, surreal, hyperreal? What do I mean when I say two numbers? This is very context dependent. However, when I say "set" it is almost always clear what I mean by that.</sub>

Comment: Ugh, I missed *two* grace periods by a few seconds!

Comment: I think we agree more than disagree. Had OP asked why don't we add the axiom that an arbitrary union of finite sets is finite, well, that would be as damaging as requiring the sum of infinitely many finite a numbers to be finite. So size does play a role.

Comment: Oh I don't say that I'm disagreeing with you. Just *somewhat* on the motivating reason. :-)

Comment: Ok, I had a slightly different intention with this post which I failed to communicate. If unioning is "something that has to be performed", then shouldn't our set theory start simply with the assumption, "If $A$ and $B$ are sets, then so is $A\cup B$" instead of the more generalized axiom of union? Can the axiom of union be proved if we start with that assumption instead?

Comment: I realize the kind of infinite sum I suggested would make no sense for real numbers. But the thought was: the infinite sum is a generalization of addition between two numbers, just as $\bigcup S$ is a generalization of unioning between two sets.

Comment: @i122554: Infinite unions are not necessarily countable unions, they are not necessarily indexed by a well-ordered set. So working one step at a time makes no sense. Moreover, even if you do have some sort of mechanism for working one step at a time, how do you get passed limit steps without essentially saying that the union of everything you have so far is also a set---which is essentially what the axiom of union telling you already?

Answer (score 2):

It's a question of size. The real numbers are of finite magnitude. There is no reason to expect a bunch of finite things to sum up to a finite thing. The correct analogy would be to compare addition of numbers with union of finite sets. Then you also would not expect the union of a bunch of finite sets to be finite. It requires more care. Similarly, you could extend the meaning of number somehow to that it would become obvious that sums always exist (this will have to be done carefully).

Another important difference is that we do not define sets, while we do define numbers. So, you can set axiomatic properties on sets any way you like (as long as you don't create a contradiction), but you can't just assert that numbers exist, since they are defined rigorously. You must prove they exit.

Comment: Numbers can be defined in terms of sets. What is *your* definition of the natural numbers? Is it not also axiomatic?

Comment: @i122554 Yes, numbers can be defined in term of sets. That does not contradict anything he said in anyway. The point is that there's a stronger restriction for an object to be a number than it is to be merely a set.

Comment: @i122554: That is irrelevant here. You can take the union of a set of numbers and perhaps get a number, or not get a number. It's just a set.

Comment: he said "we do not define sets, while we do define numbers". i don't understand the difference. what is the definition of a number?

Comment: The natural numbers can be defined in terms of sets in various ways. Any one such way is a rigorous definition of what numbers are, in terms of sets. With sets we do not give any definition of what a set is in terms of anything else. All we do is list axioms for sets. You can also take an axiomatic approach to numbers, but that won't change anything in my answer. Besides, you seem to be missing the point that the correct analogy is between addition of numbers and union of finite sets.

Comment: @i122554: We do not define sets, meaning that sets are primitive objects in mathematics (or at least they can be taken as such). The real ---or complex---numbers, however, are specific structures which can be interpreted as specific sets.

Comment: The point of my first comment was that there isn't one way to define numbers. Sets aren't "the definition" of numbers. People have taken axiomatic approaches to defining numbers, right? That is, numbers are *the primitives* in those theories. Numbers have not always been viewed as "a type of set". I'm basically repeating the same thing over and over again. And that does change something about your answer. Because if you acknowledge that the theory of numbers is a type of formal theory, then we can take liberty and define their properties in any way we wish.

Comment: You seem to cling to the second paragraph, while the first one alredy answers your question.

Comment: @i122554: We could argue that the statement you're making is not a first-order statement. Which is one option, but it is somewhat moot, since the real numbers are not a first-order based system. The answer, as I remarked in my answer on this page, is that we can derive a contradiction from the statement "every series of numbers is convergent". Simply ask yourself: if $x=\sum 1$, and what is $1+x$? It has to be $x$ again. So $x=1+x$ and therefore $0=1$. So that axiom is damaging to us. Unions, on the other hand, have not shown this sort of behavior so far.

Comment: If we define numbers in terms of sets we have restrictions on which sets are numbers and which are not.  Numbers must be finite in size or measure among other things. Any union of sets that are numbers are always sets.  But they don't need to always be numbers.

Comment: By the way, about your first paragraph: yes that's a good analogy, but I don't think it addresses what I had in mind (but maybe didn't communicate very well). It seems that you begin your answer with the assumption "numbers are things that have to model magnitude". But there are systems, that we consider "number systems", that don't model magnitude.

Comment: @i122554: I wrote in the footnote to my answer. The notion of "number" is far more fickle than the notion of "set". So first of all you are going to have to explain what does "number" even mean here. Whereas "set" being primitive, it has one interpretation in a given context, so the axiom of union makes sense in the context of ZF and the likes of it. But different number systems can be *very* different, so what exactly do you mean by "number systems", then? There is no mathematical definition for a "number".

Comment: Indeed, I said you can extend the meaning of number too. I simply pointed to the correct analogy, where there is no difficulty. Your question stems from comparing apples with pears. You notice a peculiarity of finite sets that does not exist for infinite sets. Well, that is cause they are finite.

Answer (score 0):

In response to comments about numbers defined as sets:

Numbers can be sets but not all sets are numbers.

0 = $\emptyset $

1=$\{\emptyset\} = \{0\} $

2=$\{0,1\}=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\} $

n = {0,1,2,3,.....,n-1}

etc.

Note, all numbers are finite.

$\mathbb N =\{0,1,2,3,4,....\} $ is not finite and is not a number.

We can define n + 1 as $n \cup \{n\} $ and $n+m$ as $n + 1+pred (m)$. So example $2+3=(2+1)+2=((2+1)+1)+1=\{0,1\}\cup\{2\}+1+1=\{0,1,2\}\cup\{3\}+1=\{0,1,2,3\}\cup\{4\}=\{0,1,2,3,4\}=5$.

So sums are unions.  So we can have infinite sums.  But the result may be an infinite set.  Which is *not* a number.

So we *can* assume infinite sums/unions exist but we can not assume the result is finite/a number.i.e. that the sum converges.

If it diverges it is not a finite set; not a number.